# Saving textfield value altered by textFieldDidEndEditing won't save in core data?

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

I am using the following to update a amountVAT based on textfield totalAmountInc

```
func textFieldDidEndEditing(textField: UITextField) {
    if totalAmountInc != nil {
        let tmpVAT = Double(totalAmountInc.text!)
        let valueVAT = getVATValue(tmpVAT!)

        //textfield2
        amountVAT.text = String(valueVAT)
    }
}
```

But now the value won't save (using Core Data)?

When i directly enter a  amountVAT value it will be saved.

Saving process looks like

```
func newItem(){

    let context = self.context
    let ent = NSEntityDescription.entityForName("List", inManagedObjectContext: context)


    let nItem = List(entity: ent!, insertIntoManagedObjectContext: context)
    let numberFormatter = NSNumberFormatter()

    nItem.amountVAT = numberFormatter.numberFromString(amountVAT.text!)
    .....more values
    nItem.invoiceImage = UIImagePNGRepresentation(imageHolder.image!)

    do {
     try context.save()
    } catch {
        print(error)
    }
}
func saveValues(sender: AnyObject) {

        if nItem != nil {
            editItem()
        } else {
            newItem()
        }

        dismissVC()
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to examine what the variable you are trying to save to Core Data contains. Set a breakpoint and see where you made the mistake.

In your code sample, there are a number of issues. For example, in `textFieldDidEndEditing` the text field in question is passed as the `textField` variable - no reason to refer to your instance variable and check for `nil`. (Perhaps you intended to check if the `text` property is `nil`? It is preferable to initialize it to `""` and not bother with this check. You are not explaining what `getVATValue` does, presumably just calculating a percentage. A function seems overkill for something trivial as that (and it makes your code less readable).

Check what the result of `Double(textField.text!)` is. It is likely that you find some problem with the initialization of the Double value.

Also, it does not make sense to put the value into the VAT text field, and then at save time re-convert it into a number to save in Core Data. You are using an UI element to hold  value (in an inconvenient format). Instead, you should be using variables of type `Double` to hold the values you need.

Comment: tx for the info going to try out your suggestions. getVATValue is indeed calculating a percentage but with 18 different % to choose from. As for the "should be using variables of type double" i thought the text fields only holds strings